# How to solve separable differential equation using Sympy?

Tags: python, sympy, ode

I cannot figure out how to solve this separable differential equation using sympy. Help would be greatly appreciated.

y′=(*y*−4)(*y*−2),y(0)=5

Here was my attempt, thanks in advance!!!

```
import sympy as sp


x,y,t = sp.symbols('x,y,t')

y_ = sp.Function('y_')(x)

diff_eq = sp.Eq(sp.Derivative(y_,x), (y-4)*(y-2))

ics = {y_.subs(x,0):5}

sp.dsolve(diff_eq, y_, ics = ics)
```

the output is y(x) = xy^2 -6xy +8x + 5

Comment: That's because `y` is a constant here and `y_` the function.  Have only one `y`.

Comment: With version 1.7.1, even that does not work, as the integration constant is not expanded out and thus solving `exp(2*C_1)==3` for it returns two values for the same ODE solution. The ICs solver only allows one solution without some bailout strategy of working with the first one, it's a bug.

Comment: This is also true for version 1.11.1 of sympy.live.org

Answer (score 1):

The primary error is the introduction of `y_`. This makes the variable `y` a constant parameter of the ODE and you get the wrong solution.

If you correct this you get an error of *"too many solutions for the integration constant"*. This is a bug caused by not simplifying the integration constant after it first occurs. So multiplication and addition of constants should just be absorbed, an additive constant in an exponent should become a multiplicative factor for the exponential. As it is, `exp(2*C_1)==3` has two solutions if `C_1` is considered as an angle (it's a bit of tortured logic from computing roots in the complex plane).

The newer versions can actually solve this fully if you give the third hint in the classification list `'separable', '1st_exact', '1st_rational_riccati', ...` that does something different than partial fraction decomposition of the first two

```
from sympy import *
x = Symbol('x')
y = Function('y')(x)

dsolve(Eq(y.diff(x), (y-2)*(y-4)),y,
       ics={y.subs(x,0):5}, 
       hint='1st_rational_riccati')
```

returning

```latex
\displaystyle y{\left(x \right)} = \frac{2 \cdot \left(6 - e^{2 x}\right)}{3 - e^{2 x}}
```

[image: solution formula]